# Apache Spark EC2 c4.2xlarge not launching

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, spark-ec2

When attempting to launch an EC2 cluster (c4.2xlarge) using the Apache Spark EC2 script I get the following error:

```
Don't recognize c4.2xlarge, assuming type is pvm
Spark AMI: ami-9a6e0daa
Launching instances...
ERROR:boto:400 Bad Request
ERROR:boto:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidParameterCombination</Code><Message>Virtualization type 'hvm' is required for instances of type 'c4.2xlarge'.</Message></Error></Errors
```

Any fixes?

Comment: Can you add the command you are trying to use?

Comment: sounds like the ami you're using isn't compatible with the instance type (c4 instances are hvm only)

Comment: As others have pointed out (and as is hinted at in the output above), this instance type is not supported yet. You can try [hacking the script to default to hvm](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/50ab8a6543ad5c31e89c16df374d0cb13222fd1e/ec2/spark_ec2.py#L401-L403) when it doesn't recognize the instance type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance type you are using isn't supported in the spark-ec2 script.

This is the list of the EC2 types you can use :

c1.medium, c1.xlarge,c3.2xlarge c3.4xlarge c3.8xlarge c3.large c3.xlarge cc1.4xlarge, cc2.8xlarge, cg1.4xlarge , cr1.8xlarge, hi1.4xlarge, hs1.8xlarge, i2.2xlarge, i2.4xlarge,  i2.8xlarge, i2.xlarge, m1.large, m1.medium, m1.small, m1.xlarge, m2.2xlarge, m2.4xlarge, m2.xlarge, m3.2xlarge, m3.large, m3.medium, m3.xlarge, r3.2xlarge, r3.4xlarge, r3.8xlarge, r3.large, r3.xlarge, t1.micro, t2.medium, t2.micro, t2.small

I invite you to read the script source code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/ec2/spark_ec2.py).

Comment: I made a cluster with c1.medium and none of my SPARK commands would run; they all gave me an "out of memory". This is right after the cluster boot, using EMR.

Comment: Hello @vy32 ! If you have a new question, I invite you to ask it in a new question. I don't really understand what's your issue